# phonegap + framework7 how to programmtacally set starting page?

Tags: mobile, phonegap, html-framework-7

I have application which on start lets you pick - if are you contributor or user. After that I want always load the starting page for a contributor or the user. I know you can set `<content src="index.html" />` to do it once on start, but how can I do it dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@proofzy answer is right, but you could still do it using only DOM7 instead of Jquery

Inside your JS file:

```
//to save data if user pick contributor or user button after first start.
    $$("#contributor").on('click', function(){
          localStorage.setItem("whois", "contributor");
       });

//And call this same script but for user:
    $$("#user").on('click', function(){
          localStorage.setItem("whois", "user");
       });

//So call this function on the end of page index.html and it will redirect programmatically


function check(){

   if (localStorage.getItem("whois") !== null) { //if whois exists on localStorage
       if (localStorage.getItem("whois") == "user"){ // if is USER send to User Page
            window.location.href = "userIndex.html"
       }else if (localStorage.getItem("whois") == "contributor"){ // if is USER send to contributor Page
            window.location.href = "contributorIndex.html"
       }
   }
}
```

There are many other ways to do it, even better, but this one is simplest.

Comment: This is nice and simple example too.

Answer (score 3):

You must use

> localStorage

to save data if user pick contributor or user button after first start.
Simple use jQuery script:

```
<script>
    $("#contributor").click( function()
       {
       //alert('button clicked');
       localStorage.setItem("contributor", "contributor");
       }
    );
</script>
```

And call this same script but for user:

```
<script>
    $("#user").click( function()
       {
       //alert('button clicked');
       localStorage.setItem("user", "user");
       }
    );
</script>
```

So on next html page control if user is previously press "user" or "contributor".

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

       if (localStorage.getItem("user") === null) {
           //user is null
       } else {
           document.location.href = "userIndex.html"
       }
       if (localStorage.getItem("contributor") === null) {
           //contributor is null
       } else {
           document.location.href = "contributorIndex.html"
       }
});
```

Good luck!