# How to create secure page for a mobile app using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, phonegap

I'm working a simple mobile app and I'm using HTML, CSS, Javascript, ajax, PHP and Mysql and Phonegap. The mobile app has a login and I'm using ajax to send the data to a php file located on a separate server if the login is successful the app loads a diferent page, only users that are register can see this page.

The problem that I'm facing is that when I'm on the next page I don't know how to verify that the user has the access. I was thinking on using a window variable or localstore but I don't know if this is a good idea or not.

Can some one point me in the right direction on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Just sit and think. Use `localStorage.setItem` if user is registered/logged on ajax call. Later control that on easy way. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839850/7189547) example. 
Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://exampleUrl.com/php1/insert.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#insert").val('Connecting...');
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data == "success") {
                            alert("You can login now!");
                            $("#insert").val('Wait...');
                            localStorage.setItem("logged", logged); // Save if user is successfuly registered and control on other page
                            //console.log(dataString);
                            loadiranje_paIndex();
                        } else if (data == "error") {
                            alert("Error! Try another username!");
                            $("#insert").val('Register');
                            /*location.href = '/register.html'; */
                        }
                    }
                });
```