# Open facebook native login from phonegap & web browser

Tags: cordova, facebook-login, phonegap-build, phonegap, facebook-oauth

I have a website and also need to run it on app via Phonegap Build.  I need to implement facebook login so I have put the following code in my mywebsite.com/login.html file, now on running this file on browser it gives error :

**login.html**

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Login  </title>


     <script type="text/javascript">


      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'my-app-id',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v2.12'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){

         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}

         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";

         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));



            function login()
            {


                facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "email"], function(result){

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                    facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me?fields=email,name,picture",["public_profile", "email"], function(userData){ 

                        alert(JSON.stringify(userData));

                    },function(error){
                        alert(JSON.stringify(errror));
                    });




                },function(error){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(errror));
                });



            } 




     </script>


 </head>

<body>

    <button class="loginbtn" onclick="login();">Login with Facebook</button> 

</body></html>
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined
>       at login() at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

**Question 1** : Do I need to include some sdk files to eliminate this error ?

**Question 2** :

I put this code in the index.html file of PhoneGap Build &  got the APK, on execution, it opens the Native Facebook App for Login, I logged in but after logging me in it says that URL not allowed.

What is the URL which I need to allow on my developers console of Facebook. Also how will I send the fetched details to my online server if I use this method. In this method my login UI will reside in PhoneGap local files & rest of the website code will be online on my web server. Is this possible ?

Comment: There are alot of plugins with facebook connect. Maybe you missing some files. Try another plugin

Comment: @proofzy: which files are you referring to ? can you name some of them?

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) one plugin ?

Comment: @proofzy : How do I go to next page if login is successful in my local PhoneGap app ? I am not using jquery mobile, is there any other way out? Currently index.html opens, now if on opening my app a user is already logged in, i need to redirect him to welcome.html

Comment: Here you go. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839850/7189547) example.. good luck