# use local storage to store image background position with jquery for chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, background-position

So, when I click a button what should happen is the background image center's itself, and then when I click it again it sets the background position to unset. However, my issue is that I need the user's background position choice to stay and not reset back to unset.

Here is my html button:

```
<input type="button" id="centerImgBackground" value="Center Image" name="background-image-center">
```

Here is my Jquery/JS:

```
window.onload=function(){
  isImgNotCentered = true;  
  localStorage.setItem("toCenter","center center");                                                                 
  localStorage.setItem("unCenter","unset");                                                               
  $("#centerImgBackground").click(function(){                                                                                                                                      
    if(isImgNotCentered){                                                               
      $('body').css('background-position', localStorage.getItem("toCenter"));                                                                            
      isImgNotCentered = false;                                                                            
   }                                                                       
   else {                                                                                                                  
      $('body').css('background-position',localStorage.getItem("unCenter"));

      isImgNotCentered = true;                                                                                                                                             
   }                                                                                                                                             
 });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and easy:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    localStorage.setCentered == 'center' && $('body').css('background-position','center center');

    $('#centerImgBackground').on('click', function(){
        localStorage.setCentered == 'center'? 
             ($('body').css('background-position','unset'),
             localStorage.setCentered = 'unset') :
             ($('body').css('background-position','center center'),
             localStorage.setCentered = 'center');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proper way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/229813/

```
function setBGToUnset(){
    setStyle("unset");
}

function setBGToCenter(){
    setStyle("center center");
}

function setStyle(value){
      localStorage.setItem("style",value);                
    $('body').css('background-position', localStorage.getItem("style"));  
    console.log("style saved: "+value);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var style = localStorage.getItem("style");
  console.log("default style: "+style);
    if(style != undefined && style === "unset"){
        setBGToUnset();
    } else {
        setBGToCenter();
    }
    $("#centerImgBackground").on("click", function(){
        var style = localStorage.getItem("style");
        if(style != undefined && style === "unset"){
            setBGToCenter();
        } else {
            setBGToUnset();
        }
    });
});
```

don't forget to unblock third-party cookies and site data for testing [link](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to figure out exactly what you need, so I think you're trying to do this:

```
window.onload=function(){
  isImgNotCentered = true;  


  $("#centerImgBackground").click(function(){                                                                     
    localStorage.setItem("toCenter","center center");                                                             
    if(isImgNotCentered){                                                               
      $('body').css('background-position', localStorage.getItem("toCenter"));                                                                            
      isImgNotCentered = false;                                                                            
   }                                                                       
   else {                                                                                                           
      localStorage.setItem("unCenter","unset");            
      $('body').css('background-position',localStorage.getItem("unCenter"));

      isImgNotCentered = true;                                                                                                                                             
   }                                                                                                                                             
 });

}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but when I click the button the image centers, but when I refresh my page, it uncenters.

Comment: @DimitriyKruglikov So you need check if storage has item "toCenter" or item "unCenter" and control it.. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839850/7189547) example..